# AngularJS + ng-repeat + inline-block with letter-spacing

Tags: angularjs, css, letter-spacing

I have a problem with letter-spacing for  my inline-block elements. As you see [there(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/2XSSs/) my lower elems are collapse, because they are not separate with '\n' or gap.
If I repeat that with Angular, I have collapse elems. How can I fix this problem?

```
<a ng-repeat="menu in menus"">{{menu.name}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to put some spacing after each element, just add this line to your css, inside you ".parent a" selector. Here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2XSSs/2/)

```
margin-left: 10px;
```

Comment: It doesn't fix my problem, because active-aria for links not separate.

Comment: Right, it has to be with margin. Have a look now @PaulKononenko